# Use "ADODB.Stream" to convert ANSI to UTF-8, miss 1-2 character in the first row

Tags: excel, vba, utf-8

I need to convert "ANSI" csv file to "UTF-8" csv file.
Below code can work, but the first character miss 
Please see attached screen shot, 
the original file : Customer
the output file : 﨏ustomer

```
Function Convert(myFileIn, myFileOut)
  Dim stream ,strTextText
  Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

  stream.Open
  stream.Type = 2 'text
  stream.LoadFromFile myFileIn
  stream.Position = 0
  stream.Charset = "gb2312"
  strText = stream.ReadText
  stream.Close

  stream.Open
  stream.Type = 2
  stream.Position = 0
  stream.Charset = "utf-8"
  stream.WriteText strText
  stream.SaveToFile myFileOut, 2
  stream.Close
  Set stream = Nothing

End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You have to set

```
stream.Type
```

and

```
stream.Charset
```

before you open the stream.

And stream.Position is 0 by default.

Greetings

Axel

Comment: Really helps. thanks!